# Cant figure out how to create an structure array based on a certain part of another structure

Tags: c++, arrays, string, sorting, struct

*inb4 the problem - in my country we have cities, and then the cities are in bigger things, kinda like states in USA, so for this task i will call cities cities, and those bigger things states, for example there are  cities A, B and C. A and B are in a state X, and C is in a state Y.*

I am preparing for my exam tommorow by doing exams from years before, and there is this task, that asks you to output to a file structures, which consist of the name of the state, then the number of people living in the states smallest city, and then the overall number of people living in the state. At the beginning you are given a info file. **The first number is the amount of cities** that the program will have to work on, lets call it k. Then there are many lines, who look like this:

`CITYNAME STATE NUMBEROFPPL`       for example:

```
Buffalo  New York     300000
```

This is what my info file looks like:

```
15

Vilnius             Vilniaus     541278

Dusetos             Utenos       4211

Alytus              Alytaus      69859

Druskininkai        Alytaus      16890

Ignalina            Utenos       6307

Kavarskas           Utenos       753

Lazdijai            Alytaus      5027

Simnas              Alytaus      1940

Trakai              Vilniaus     5504

Utena               Utenos       33086

Veisiejai           Alytaus      1673

Vievis              Vilniaus     5246

Lentvaris           Vilniaus     11832

Visaginas           Utenos       28438

Zarasai             Utenos       8001
```

I can read the file easily, I construct an array of structures, called City, so it looks like this in main:

```
City A[102] // Thats the maximum number of cities
```

and in struct it looks like:

```
struct City 
{ string name;
  string state;
  int peoplelivinginit;
}
```

NOW HERE IS THE PROBLEM - I need to find how many DIFFERENT states there are in the given cities and construct an array of structures for them (structures like:

```
string nameofthestate;
string citiesinstate[102];
int overallnumberofpeopleinstate;
int peoplelivinginthesmallestcityofthestate;
```

)

I dont know how I can find how many different states are in the array of structures, i tried sort to sort them out and then maybe remove duplicates, but it just sounds like such a hassle and I also failed to use sort, because we havent learned how to use it yet, and I dont think that is how we are supposed to do this task.

Please just tell me how I can find how many and what different states there are, I think i could do it from there.

Here is what ive done so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
struct City
{
    string name;
    string state;
    int n; //number of people in the city
};

void Read (City A[], int & k)
{
    ifstream fd;
    fd.open("Info.txt");
    fd >> k;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        fd.ignore();
        char namee[21];
        fd.get(namee, 21);
        A[i].name = namee;
        char statee[14];
        fd.get(statee, 14);
        A[i].state = statee;
        fd >> A[i].n;
    }
    fd.close();
}


int main()
{
    City A[102];
    int k;
    Read (A, k);
    City B[102] = A;

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        cout << B[i].name << " " << B[i].state << " " << B[i].n << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT::: Here is what the end result should look like:

```
3
Utenos   753  80796
Alytaus  1673 95389
Vilniaus 5246 563860
```

EDIT2:
**Thank you for all the answers**. I noticed that most of you suggest using vector, map, bool and etc, but I haven't even heard of those things yet, as I have just finished high school and my final exam for IT was today. I am glad to say that I have definitely passed, will probably have around 85-95%, so its really good. Since I plan on studying computer science in university, I will check out the things you  mentioned, as I will probably need them in the future.

Comment: *"but it just sounds like such a hassle"* - yes, well, sometimes programming requires you to do a bunch of work.

Comment: Seems like you have chosen the wrong data structure .. You should used a linked list, then you can have a linked list of cities and a linked list of states, the states can each have a list of cities. That way you will only have the one set of data but it will be distributed into different data types.

Comment: See the problem is, my programming skills are very limited, i dont even know what a linked list is.

Answer (score 1):

You have City, about which you have information, and concept State, about which you have little more than the name and the knowledge that it contains Cities.

Your City structure seems sound to me.

State can be something along the lines of

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<City>> states;
```

This is a ordered mapping of a string (which will be the name of each state) to a list of cities. The list of cities for a state can be accessed states["name of state"] just like you would an array,except you get to use the state name instead of a number.

```
bool Read (std::map<std::string, std::vector<City>> & states)
{
    int k;
    ifstream fd("Info.txt");
    if (!(fd >> k))
    {
        //bad file. do something.
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        std::string name;
        std::string state;
        int population;

        if (fd >> name >> state >> population)
        {
            City city(name, state, population);
            states[state].push_back(city);
        }  
        else
        {
            //bad file. do something.
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

At the end of this function all of the cities have been assigned to objects. Each city object has been placed into lists organized by state.

Finding the number of states is easy: `states.size()`.

Finding the number of cities in Vilniaus: `states["Vilniaus"].size()`

Summing the population of Vilniaus:

```
int sum = 0;
for(City city: states["Vilniaus"])
{
    sum += city.n;
}
```

Smallest number of people is similar:

```
int min = std::numeric_limits<int>::max(); // or just use some arbitrary huge number
for(City city: states["Vilniaus"])
{
    if (city.n < min)
    {
        min = city.n;
    }
}
```

Getting a list of states is a bit tricky because the map stores `std::pair` and `std::pair` groups the state name and the City:

```
for (auto state: states)
{
    string statename = state.first; // City is at state.second
    // do something with statename
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It often helps to look at what you have and what you want:

You have a list of entries, each representing a city with some associated information. This can be - as you have done - packed pretty well into a structure:

```
struct CityEntry {
    string name;
    string state;
    unsigned int inhabitants;
};
```

You want a list of states with some information that must be computed from your input. So you could try to put that into a structure, too:

```
struct StateEntry {
    string name;
    unsigned int total_inhabitants;
    unsigned int lowest_inhabitants;
};
```

**But**, there is an additional requirement: Uniqueness. You don't want more than one instance of the above structure with the same name. So in fact for each name (of a state) there is exactly one associated "pack" of information. This is a pretty common pattern, so there is a solution for it: `std::map`

You map each name of a state to its associated information:

```
struct StateInhabitants {
    unsigned int total;
    unsigned int lowest;
    // constructor needed, see full source
};
// ... map<string, StateInhabitants>
```

This is the representation of "what I want". Next you need to convert the "what I have" to "what I want". Since your input is a list, without any dependencies between its elements, you can simply iterate over it, extracting
the information you need:

```
vector<CityEntry> cities = read_cities();
map<string, StateInhabitants> state_info;
for (CityEntry const & city : cities) {
    // accessing an entry of a map via operator[] creates
    // the entry if it isn't there yet.
    StateInhabitants & inhabitants = state_info[city.state];
    inhabitants.total += city.inhabitants;
    inhabitants.lowest = std::min(inhabitants.lowest, city.inhabitants);
}
```

Finally, you can print your results by iterating over the map.

You may ask why I'm not storing the cities of a state for each state: In cases like this, I try to follow [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it). Storing them would add complexity: because it's not the representation I intend to present as solution, I would need another step to transform that intermediate representation into the final one.

Unless, of course, you actually need the list of cities in each state.

So, to sum up: Look at what you have, look what you want, including possibly rather hidden requirements (such as uniqueness in this case). Search whether there is a partial solution to your requirements (`std::set` provides uniqueness but no additional information, `std::map` provides both). Extend that to actually fit your problem.

[Full example code.](https://gist.github.com/musteresel/8db818354a598b7fee86)